# Feed javascript parameter with django model value

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am working on a website with Django, and  I want to include a 3D viewer (three.js) which read an object file selected by the user.

So, I get all 3D objects files via a call from my Django model in the template:

**HTML body**

```
{% for 3dobj in 3dobj _list %}
<li>{{ 3dobj.path}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And then, I would like that by selecting one object of my list, it will feed my javascript function with the path "/media/3D_object_1.obj"

**JS**

```
var onLoadMtl = function ( materials ) {
objLoader.setModelName( modelName );
objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
objLoader.getLogger().setDebug( true );
objLoader.load( '/media/3D_object_1.obj', callbackOnLoad, null, null, null, false );
};
```

How could I do that ?

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: this '/media/`3D_object_1.obj` stands for what?, is it something that you will retrieve from your django loop?

Comment: @Lemayzeur : it is in fact the path of the object to visualize. This path is get from Django through the model associated.

Comment: @hansTheFranz: thank you, I am looking how it works :)

Comment: if you do select an object by clicking, set an attribute to `<li data-id='{{3dobj.id}}'></li>`, a js `onclick` event, where you can retrieve the attribute of the clicked object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @hansTheFranz and @Lemayzeur, I managed to do it using onclick event combined with django:

```
  {% for viewerfile in viewerfile_list %}
  <li onclick=updateFileViewed(this.innerHTML)>{{ viewerfile.path }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```